# Any Migration tool AS2 to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

HI All,

I have a AS2 code. I want to change AS3.

Any Migration tool AS2 to AS3.

Please help me. thanks

WIth regards
Viswa

Answer (score 0):

http://www.electrotank.com/junk/jobe/AS2_to_AS3.zip

Instructions and everything inside. This might help you for small bits of code but for a proper conversion i am afraid there is no magic tool.

Good luck :)

PS: More info [here](http://jobemakar.blogspot.com/2007/05/convert-actionscript-2-to-actionscript.html)